# iOS App Store: How to handle multiple versions of an app that points to different backends?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have one app but I have different backends for Production and Testing to isolate the data between the two.  This means that when I upload a version of the app to the App Store, it is locked-in pointing to either the Testing or Production backend.  Since each version of the app uploaded to the App Store must be its own unique version, I'll have some versions that are 'test-only' that will never be promoted to production and other that are 'production-only'.  Is there a better way to handle this situation, either within the App Store or within my Swift code itself?

Comment: Why do you upload test version to the AppStore? That is not where they belong... You normally do this with some build flags in Xcode that configure the backend for a build, see e.g. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-create-development-staging-and-production-configs-in-xcode-ec58b2cc1df4 - your Swift code should not know about it, at least not directly.

Comment: Make the server selection configurable in some hidden developer settings menu, which is only visible after you enter a magic password, or tied to a specific user account.

Answer (score 0):

After working with TestFlight more, I settled on the pattern of having all builds for the same release use the same semantic release version and just change the build number.

I may take this a step further and use different build number schemes between the Testing builds and the Production builds.  This would make the distinction between test and production builds much more explicit within TestFlight.

Another solution that requires more setup but creates an even cleaner separation would be to create separate Apps in App Store Connect with the intention that your non-Production Apps would never be released to the public App Store.  I could see this being a great solution if your app had to go through multiple test environments.  There would be some more overhead (i.e. a lot more builds and separate targets to maintain) but you would never have to worry about accidentally submitting a version of your app whose backend points to a test environment instead of a production environment.  For more details on this type of solution, I recommend https://savvyapps.com/blog/using-testflight-to-distribute-multiple-versions-ios-app.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but the second solution here is what I ended up using. I have our "sandbox" app setup with its own app id, certs, profiles etc. When I build my app using CI/CD I have separate code branches "main" and "sandbox". So, sandbox gets built to the "test/qa" version of my app  that is never released to the app store. Once we are satisfied the sandbox code is merged into main and we build the production app out of that branch. Never the twain shall meet. Also main will never have a version > sandbox version. It works but yes it is a bit more work